# Terminal emulator with tab saving functionality?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there a terminal emulator that will save tabs across sessions/reboots, including tab title, working directory for each tab and maybe even command history, or even restart a running program?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are using for 'tabs' but I recommend a terminal multiplexer with multiple panes. Then...

Get `tmux`. Then look at plugins...it has a couple that will do at least some of what you want: https://github.com/tmux-plugins

`tmux-resurrect` is probably the most capable. The general session/pane/directory/etc restoration is solid and I use it regularly. Combine it with `tmux-continuum` and you'll get auto save/restore.

It is relatively limited as far as which programs can be restored in a running state: vi, vim, nvim, emacs, man, less, more, tail, top, htop, irssi, mutt. You can apparently customize it to restore other programs but in the short amount of time that I've experimented with it it seemed a bit rough.

If restoring running programs isn't your primary focus you might also look at https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator. It uses a slightly different approach to saving sessions but it is fundamentally similar to resurrect.